# PostgresSQL Data importation using COPY

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, database-migration

I have a  CSV file with 13 columns; Id,Assigned_to,Title,Serial_number,Description, Price, Date_assigned,Purchase_date,is_assigned,is_cleared_off,is_damaged, created_at, updated_at.e terminal

I am trying to import the data to a PostgreSQL server using the terminal.

I am using the following command;
COPY assets(id,assigned_to,title,serial_number,description,price,date_assigned,purchase_date,is_assigned,is_damaged,created_at,updated_at) FROM '/home/intern2/Documents/assets_final.csv' DELIMITER ‘,’ CSV HEADER;
where /home/intern2/Documents is the file directory and the file name is assets_final.csv

I am however getting this error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "‘"
LINE 1: ...ome/intern2/Documents/assets_final.csv' DELIMITER ‘,’ CSV HE...

Comment: `‘` should be `'`

Comment: I have 2 comments regarding the question: 1) Please use code snippets/sections to make your question more readable.  
2) Please ask an explicit question e.g "Can you please help me in understanding why I am getting this error ?"